# Currency pipe wrong format

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In my angular 4 project I want to display some italian amouts, so I am using the default standard currency pipe like:
`{{amount | currency:'EUR':true}}`

But it shows a number formatted like this: `€12.00` that is not the italian standard, I expect something like : `€12,00`

As I see in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) the pipe depends from i18n API and in my browser is supported [browser-support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) ( I am using chrome latest)

Using this : `providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'it-IT'}]`
formats correctly the currency but I don't want a default LOCALE.

So Why this pipe don't understand automatically the LOCALE?

Answer (score -1):

Create a new Pipe like this

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'CurrencyFilter',
    pure: false
})
export class CurrencyFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: number): any {
        var OrigionalValue = items;
        var stringValue = OrigionalValue.toString(); // to get comma we must convert it to string 
        var CommaValue = stringValue.replace('.', ',');
        var finalValue = "€" + CommaValue;
        return finalValue;
    }
}
```

{{amount | CurrencyFilter}}

Comment: This solve the problem only for that case...it don't solve the problem for any languages, I need a solution valid based on the Locale_Id

Comment: @Alessandro can you please look into https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11820